# Does $M_\odot$ go in normal text or in cursive?

Tags: notation

The questions is just the title. I understand we're supposed to not use cursive wherever we write units (so if I write m as a variable, it goes like $m$, but if it indicates metres, then it goes as m).

So, if I'm writing on a LaTeX table that the mass (noted as $M$ is measured in solar masses, should I use $M_\odot$ or M$_\odot$?

Comment: This will probably be closed as opinion-based, but the answer is just that if you're doing it for a class, it doesn't matter unless your instructor is extremely picky. And if your instructor is picky, then the answer is whatever they happen to like better, and you find that out by asking them.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're writing a research paper, you just look at what other papers in the journal you want to submit to have done. I've seen both formats. It also doesn't matter -- if the editor really cares, they'll just change it to the one they want later.